# Rails: how can I nest only associated resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To set up nested resources in Rails, I have seen example routes given like this:

```
map.resources :players
map.resources :teams, :has_many => :players
```

By doing this, you can visit teams/1/players and see a list. But it lists all players, not just those that belong to team 1.

How can I list only the resources that are associated with the parent resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the team first.  A common practice is to do this in a before filter.

```
class PlayersController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :get_team

  def get_team
    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
  end

  def index
    @players = @team.players # add pagination, etc., if necessary
  end

  def show
    @player = @team.players.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Note that the code above insists that you specify a team.  If you want the same controller to work for both, you need to change it slightly (i.e. check for `params[:team_id]`).

You can use the excellent inherited_resources gem to DRY this up if you controller logic is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has little to do with `map.resources` and routing in general.

Note, players are not fetched magically by the framework: there's some action in some controller processing `teams/1/players` request and your code there fetches list of players to show. Examining that action (or posting here) should help.